# How do I send automatic Thank You emails for different donation amounts and donation types?

Tags: email

For example, I want send an automatic thank you templated email to someone using 1 email template for there "generous donation" for donations over $1,000. -- included would be some extra emotion graphics.

Whereas I would like to send automatic thank email using a 2nd email template that thanks someone is a less intense way for donations of $100 dollars or less.

Likewise, I would like to send different templates for donations of different types -- wire transfer, check, even service donations (e.g. want to provide free marketing services)

Answer (score 6):

I've not tried this, but the Smarty mail template allows for conditional statements. So you maybe could create one email with different outputs,

Some older tutorials:

- https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC42/Smarty+in+mail+templates
- https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=295109201

Another option could be to use CiviRules, which triggers actions at different points, e.g. send mail y when contribution of z amount is made:

- https://docs.civicrm.org/civirules/en/latest/
- https://civicrm.org/extensions/civirules

Comment: CiviRules is the way to go here!  Though using tokens can reduce the number of permutations you have, CiviRules requires less tech expertise.

Comment: Thank you, Nic, will try and get back! Happy New Year!